# How to create compound documents?

Tags: json-api

I'm thinking of using the [JSONAPI](http://jsonapi.org) standard for the design of our API. One thing this API must be able to do, is accept a compound document (several layers deep) and create it. The root object owns all descendants ('to-many' relationships) which the server knows nothing about at that point, so it's not possible for the client to provide an id.

Is this supported by the specification or does the client have to issue http requests for every object in the document in order?

Answer (score 6):

from  http://jsonapi.org/format/#document-compound-documents

> Compound documents require "full linkage", meaning that every included
>   resource MUST be identified by at least one resource identifier object
>   in the same document. These resource identifier objects could either
>   be primary data or represent resource linkage contained within primary
>   or included resources. The only exception to the full linkage
>   requirement is when relationship fields that would otherwise contain
>   linkage data are excluded via sparse fieldsets.

```
{
  "data": [{
    "type": "articles",
    "id": "1",
    "attributes": {
      "title": "JSON API paints my bikeshed!"
    },
    "links": {
      "self": "http://example.com/articles/1"
    },
    "relationships": {
      "author": {
        "links": {
          "self": "http://example.com/articles/1/relationships/author",
          "related": "http://example.com/articles/1/author"
        },
        "data": { "type": "people", "id": "9" }
      },
      "comments": {
        "links": {
          "self": "http://example.com/articles/1/relationships/comments",
          "related": "http://example.com/articles/1/comments"
        },
        "data": [
          { "type": "comments", "id": "5" },
          { "type": "comments", "id": "12" }
        ]
      }
    }
  }],
  "included": [{
    "type": "people",
    "id": "9",
    "attributes": {
      "first-name": "Dan",
      "last-name": "Gebhardt",
      "twitter": "dgeb"
    },
    "links": {
      "self": "http://example.com/people/9"
    }
  }, {
    "type": "comments",
    "id": "5",
    "attributes": {
      "body": "First!"
    },
    "links": {
      "self": "http://example.com/comments/5"
    }
  }, {
    "type": "comments",
    "id": "12",
    "attributes": {
      "body": "I like XML better"
    },
    "links": {
      "self": "http://example.com/comments/12"
    }
  }]
}
```

Comment: This assumes that you know the IDs of the resources you are creating, to put into the relationships and included documents. Although I suppose you could give a special value to the unknown IDs and have the server create them.